# simple message error on else

Tags: syntax-error, processing

I am currently making a soundboard that plays sound when you click on a button (first mini project so its quite exciting), and when I try to use an `else` statement in my project I get a compile error.

Can anyone tell me what my problem is? I would love to learn why this happened so this won't happen in the future.

I've tried using `else if` but I get a syntax error so I'm lost in what I should be doing.

Here's the problematic part of my code:

```
void mousePressed(){
if (mouseX > 100 && mouseX < 100 + width
&& mouseY > 100 && mouseY < 100+height)
    s2.play();
    image(p2,1,1);
} else{  //here is where i get the error
  s2.pause();
  s2.rewind();
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `if (){}` add brackets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use proper indentation to really see what's going on:

```
void mousePressed(){
   if (mouseX > 100 && mouseX < 100 + width && mouseY > 100 && mouseY < 100+height)
      s2.play();

   image(p2,1,1);
} 
else{
  s2.pause();
  s2.rewind();
}
```

**Your if statement does not have an opening curly bracket `{` after it**, so it only evaluates the next line. Then the following closing curly bracket `}` closes the `mousePressed()` function. After that you have your `else`, which doesn't make sense. That's not valid syntax. That's why you get the error.

To fix it, you probably just want to add an opening curly bracket `{` after your `if` statement:

```
void mousePressed(){
   if (mouseX > 100 && mouseX < 100 + width && mouseY > 100 && mouseY < 100+height){
      s2.play();
      image(p2,1,1);
   } 
   else{
     s2.pause();
     s2.rewind();
   }
}
```

Comment: How did i not see that problem ahha. thank you so much Sir

Comment: @antc You didn't see it because you weren't using proper indentation. If you're using the Processing editor, you can press `ctrl+t` to have Processing automatically format your code for you.